# Accessing a share from a sql server job

Tags: sql-server, share, sql-server-agent

I'm trying to run a SQL job (sql server 2008) every day that needs to read a file stored on another server. I have set up a share and I can access it using my user through windows explorer.

Then I set up the sql job to "run as" that same user, but it doesn't seem to be able to access the file.

I set up Delegation in Active Directory (windows 2003). This didn't solve the issue.

How can i access the file in the share?

Answer (score 0):

Does that user have access to sqlcmd or whichever command line tools you're using to run the SQL?...Does that user have access to all the sql server obujects in the sql?

Comment: Yes, the user has complete access. I'm doing a simple BULK INSERT within a stored procedure which is called by the SQL agent job. This stored procedure runs without a problem when run in SQL Server Management Studio instead of by the job.